# Complicated RegEx: get all strings that end with ":any-number-here" between brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I got a very specific regex to build and as a newbie I never tried something like this, since its very specific, I am finding difficult to get some nice examples.

I want to get every part of a string that ends with colon and any number, inside brackets. This may be confusing, so I'll get examples of what it should catch.

*This should match:*

`[hello everyone example string:23]`

`[http://www.google.com:9234523]`

`[the temperature for today is:783]`

*this don't*

`[hello everyone example string:]`

`[hello everyone example string23]`

So far I could get this to find all inside brackets with this php code:

`preg_match_all("/\[[^\]]*\]/", $string, $result);`

Any tips? Thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following regex should work:

```
\[.*:\d+\]
```

You can test it here for example:
http://regexpal.com/

So the following should work for you:

```
preg_match_all("/\[.*:\d+\]/", $string, $result);
```

in php, the regex should start and end with an unique delimiter, here it's "/" but you can use "|", "#" or anything else.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I didn't know this website :D I think its time o learn regex since I need it many times.